# Filter a sharepoint list dynamically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, wss, sharepoint-designer

I have a task list which contains tasks which are submitted on the end date of every project phase. I need a list view which displays the submissions for the most recent project phase.

Currently, this is implemented by specifying the most recent project phase end date as a filter condition. Whenever the tasks for the new project phase are submitted, the filter condition specified earlier becomes invalid, and the filter condition which has to be manually changed to the new project phase end date.

Is there any way to remove the manual step here, and get the list to display only those items which has the highest date value?

I am looking for a solution which doesnt involve any custom development. Any out-of-the-box solution or some customization using SharePoint designer is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Could you group (rather than filter) on date created or the task due date (if specified)?  Or does the spec require that all other tasks are not visible on this view?

Comment: Yes, the spec requires that none of the other tasks be visible

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is the project fase in another list and are the tasks referencing that list (i.e. a lookup column)?

If so, you could use sharepoint designer to create a datasource that shows the top 1 result of the project fase list, sorted by date descending. Then, using the result of that you filter your other datasource (i.e. the actual tasks list) to display only the tasks that match that date.